# Having multiple timers Work separately using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

so here is my question

i am trying to create a timer, and that timer is created for every client created, so its actually 1 Div (this is a small chunk of the actual code, my problem is only with the timer)

```
<div class="timer">
  <input src="/images/playButton.png" type="image" class="btnPlay" />
  <div class="clock">
      <span class="min">00</span>
      <span class="s">:</span>
      <span class="sec">00</span>
  </div>
```

and here is the javascript behind this timer that makes it all work

```
$j('.btnPlay').click(function () {
    var clock = $j(this).parent().children('.clock');

    function pad(val) {
        return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
    }

    timerObject = (function startTimer() {
        clock.children('.sec').text(pad(++sec % 60));
        clock.children('.min').text(pad(parseInt(sec / 60, 10)));
    });
    //the 1000(milliseconds) means execute function every 1 second
    timer = setInterval(timerObject, 1000);


 }// end of play button if statement
```

now here is the main problem with this code, the first timer works perfectly fine, but for some reason, when i play my second timer, the time will start where the first timer left off, i know there is a lot of similar questions out there, but most of those people are using 2 different divs for there timer, i am forced to use One, any advice or fix would be highly appreciated, been stuck on this for quite long.

Comment: the variables are in global scope

Comment: Is that what you looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/87x659dz/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using global variables for `sec` and `timer`. To fix this, you could use jQuery's [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) and [`.removeData()`](https://api.jquery.com/removedata/) functions so each timer has its own set of those values.

```
function pad(val) {
    return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val;
}

$j(function($) {
    $('.btnPlay').click(function() {
        var $timer = $(this).closest('.timer'),
            $clock = $timer.find('.clock');
        $timer.data('sec', 0);
        if (!$timer.data('interval')) {
            $timer.data('interval', setInterval(function() {
                var sec = $timer.data('sec') + 1;
                $clock.children('.sec').text(pad(sec % 60));
                $clock.children('.min').text(pad(Math.floor(sec / 60)));
                $timer.data('sec', sec);
            }, 1000));
        }
    });
});
```

In order to stop the interval for a timer, you would use:

```
clearInterval($timer.data('interval'));
$timer.removeData('interval');
```

Note: You could make this more efficient by using a single interval for all the timers.

---

You might not care, but since `setInterval()` is *not* guaranteed to get called exactly every second, the timer is not very accurate. The following would be more accurate:

```
        $timer.data('start', Date.now());
        if (!$timer.data('interval')) {
            $timer.data('interval', setInterval(function() {
                var sec = Math.floor((Date.now() - $timer.data('start')) / 1000);
                $clock.children('.sec').text(pad(sec % 60));
                $clock.children('.min').text(pad(Math.floor(sec / 60)));
            }, 1000));
        }
```

Comment: hey john, so the above code actually worked out perfectly, i'm having problems with stopping the timer though, it doesnt really stop at all once i press the pause button, but it does start over when i press the play button, which i understand why.

Comment: @ledia - I see I was missing a closing parenthesis on the line with the call to `Math.floor()`. I'm guessing you already realized that if this is working for you.

Comment: @ledia - Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zo9kv36s/). It shows the stopping of the timer working. I also moved the code that updates the clock display into a separate function so it can be called when the timer is started, so the clock clears to zero right away.

Comment: yes i had to change a couple of things to make it work with my program, i'm not an expert in javascript at all, i just saw your jsfiddle and figured out why its not working and fixed it, thank you so much for your help and i hope you have a wonderful day

Comment: one last question john, is there a way i can keep the timer value instead of having it start over from 0 ? i dont think that should be complicated at all

Comment: @ledia - I had a feeling you might want that -- since you called the button "Pause", rather than "Stop". How do you want it to work? If the time is "01:15" when the pause button is pressed should it start at "01:15" when the start button is pressed again? Or does the time keep going in the background? Also, I showed two techniques in my answer. Are you using the first or second?

Comment: i want it to continue from 01:15, without having the timer going in the background, right now i'm using the first technique but i will be switching to the second one by tonight, i didnt know that setInterval is not guaranteed to run every 1 second, and this needs to be precise

Comment: @ledia - Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zo9kv36s/5/) with the pause button implemented. The timer now needs to keep track of how much time elapse (in milliseconds) when it was paused so it can adjust the start time accordingly when it is restarted.

Comment: weird, for some reason it deleted the last comment you posted, but anyways... that was an interesting fix, and i just swithced to your second technique, little work had to be done and changed to make it work with my stuff, but this was great. I thank you again and I seriously appreciate the help you have provided me.

Comment: @ledia - I had temporarily deleted my comment because I made a slight modification to the jsfiddle. You might want to look at the jsfiddle again. It also occurred to me that you might want to be able to get the final time when the timer is stopped, here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zo9kv36s/6/) that shows how to do that.